# How to transfer Core Foundation ownership with a mix of Create/Get?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

Is it correct to use `CFBridgingRelease` in the following code?

```
CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
PopulateArray(&items);    
CFDictionaryRef dict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
CFData data = CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, "key");

NSMutableArray* datas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:CFBridgingRelease(data), nil];
return datas;
```

According to the [Get Rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-SW1) I'm just getting `data` so I don't own it, and shouldn't be transferring ownership. But my reasoning is that ultimately `data` *is* being created here inside the `items` structure, and I'm returning it in an array so I want it to be reference-counted afterwards so I *should* transfer ownership.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to the Get Rule I'm just getting data so I don't own it, and shouldn't be transferring ownership.

Correct, to transfer ownership you must have ownership, and you don't. Transferring ownership when you don't have it is dangerous, expect crashes.

> But my reasoning is that ultimately data is being created here inside the items structure, and I'm returning it in an array so I want it to be reference-counted afterwards so I should transfer ownership.

No, what you do is just transfer the reference *without* ownership:

```
(__bridge NSData *)data
```

And now ARC will track the result of that expression. When you place the resulting reference in your `NSMutableArray` the array will take ownership. At this point your data has at least two owners, `items` and `datas`. ARC manages the lifetime of `datas` and any objects it refers to, however you must release `items` yourself when it is no longer needed. You can release it immediately after you've placed your data in `datas` if you do not otherwise need it.

HTH

Comment: If you transfer it without ownership, why would the array take ownership? Is that just a side-effect of `initWithObjects`? I was under the impression that NS* objects won't take ownership of CF stuff unless you explicitly tell it to.

Comment: The cast `(__bridge NSData *)` returns a reference value of type `NSData *`, which is a type ARC tracks, formally it is a value of *retainable object pointer type*. The standard `NS` collections are all *strong* collections of retainable object references and as such take ownership of any reference stored in them, relinquishing that ownership when a reference is removed or the collection itself destroyed. The collections; and strong (the default kind) variables; do not care if references stored in them are owned or not they still take ownership themselves. HTH

Comment: Ah, I get it. `CFBridgingRelease` essentially saves us the effort of `CFRelease`ing the object but in my case it will get released when I clean up the `items` array.

Comment: Sort of, you would never call `CFRelease` on `data` as you don't own it, hence you also can't use `CFBridgingRelease`. However `data` is owned (at least) by `items`, and when you release that it `data` will be released (and potentially destroyed, dependent on the number of owners).